# Is it all right to answer own question with a summary of a discussion from the comments in case no other answers are posted?

Tags: discussion, self-answer

I've asked a [question](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/36362/word-order-in-%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A-%D7%94%D7%91%D7%90) on [Linguistics.SE](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/).

My question has received no direct answers (yet), but a very interesting discussion took place in the comments. I believe that reading through it pretty much helped me understand and formulate the answer. I would like to answer my own question with a summary of that discussion, listing every participant and quoting them. The discussion itself was overburdened by a couple of discrepancies in terminology, which might be interesting, yet it clearly is not related to the question itself.

Is this a decent thing to do?

Comment: In short: Yes, that's OK. Especially as you plan to cite and mention the original commenters.